# how to select all elements containing at least one [attr=name1] element which, in its turn, contain at least one [attr=name2] element?

Tags: jquery

I have this markup:

```
<div class="click">click</div>
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="container">
<div data-attrfirst='type1'><span data-attrsecond='type2'>must be red</span></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to select all the `.container`s that:
1. are inside of `#wrapper`;
2. contain `data-attrfirst='type1'` element which, in its turn, contain `data-attrsecond='type2'` element.
My requirements:
1. My '#wrapper', 'type1', 'type2' values MUST be kept as variables.
2. I MUST find this all inside of some tag (in this case, I choose `body`).

I tried this (asterisks may be removed, no difference):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.click').click(function () {
            var myid = '#wrapper';
            var attrfirst = 'type1';
            var attrsecond = 'type2';
            var elem = $('*[data-attrfirst=' + attrfirst + ']').has('*[data-attrsecond=' + attrsecond + ']');
            $('body').find(myid + ' .container').each(function (i) {
                if ($(this).has('*[data-attrfirst=' + attrfirst + '] *[data-attrsecond=' + attrsecond + ']')) {
                    $(this).css('color', 'red')
                }
            });

            $('body').find(myid + ' .container').each(function (i) {
                if ($(this).has(elem)) {
                    $(this).css('color', 'red')
                }
            });
            $('body').find(myid + ' .container').filter(function (i) {
                return $('*[data-attrfirst=' + attrfirst + '] *[data-attrsecond=' + attrsecond + ']', this).length >= 1
            }).css('color', 'red')
        });
    });
</script>
```

Where am I wrong? And I don't understand from Jquery docs, does `.has` accept Jquery object?

Comment: Sorry, but where's your `.container` in your HTML markup?

Comment: Edits saved. I have to try again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question says that you want to find the `#container`, so use this:

```
$('body #wrapper .container:has([data-attrfirst="type1"] [data-attrsecond="type2"])');
```

Or, to be a little less confusing, you can work backwards:

```
$('[data-attrfirst="type1"] [data-attrsecond="type2"]')
     .closest('body #wrapper .container');
```

---

However, from your code it seems that you actually want to find that last `data-attrsecond="type2"` element. In that case, use this:

```
$('body #wrapper .container [data-attrfirst="type1"] [data-attrsecond="type2"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find `.container` but you have defined 'container' as an id attribute not a class attribute. `#container` should return you the elements you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
attrfirst = 'type1';
attrsecond = 'type2';
thetag = 'body';

$(thetag + " #wrapper [data-attrfirst='" + attrfirst + "'] [data-attrsecond='" + attrsecond + "']").css('color', 'red')
```